# WidgetKit Inheritance from non-protocol type

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, xcode12, widgetkit

I wanted to create a WidgetExtension, so I proceeded exactly like the codealong provided by Apple, creating a new Widget Extension Target. However, an error(actually 8) show up, like in the screenshot below. This is in the boilerplate code by Apple, this error does not show in their codealong and I don‘t know why it is, I found some similar problems but their solving method did not work for me.

[image: Auto created sample code]

Comment: Look through source for other Mensa type, looks like there is duplication conflict.